# How to reload observable with new data?

Tags: angular, angular6, angular8

I have singltone service with Observable, that takes data from server and display it:

```
class HttpService {
   constructor() {
     this.$blocks = this.managerService
      .get()
      .pipe(shareReplay(1));

   }
}
```

In template I use `async`:

```
public blocks: any;

ngOnInit() {
  this.blocks = this.httpService.$blocks;
}


<div *ngFor="let block of blocks | async"></div>
```

How to reload this observable `blocks | async` from another component, I mean request again data and reflesh list?

Problem is async only one time subscribes and if there are changes in server I can not get them

Comment: Can you share the way you would like to refresh it? There are multiple ways of doing so and which way is best is dependent on that.

Comment: Or maybe a StackBlitz?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One quick way would be to forgo `async` pipe and subscribe to the observable in the controller in a function. You could then call this function whenever you wish to reload the data using `EventEmitter` from the child component.

Singleton

```js
class HttpService {
  getData() {
    return this.managerService.get()
      .pipe(shareReplay(1));
   }
}
```

Component A - Controller

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-component-a'
})
export class ComponentA implements OnInit {
  public blocks: any;
  dataSubscription: any;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getData();
  }

  getData() {
    if (this.dataSubscription) {  // cancel pending HTTP requests before triggering new request
      this.dataSubscription.unsubscribe();
    }

    this.dataSubscription = this.httpService.getData().subscribe(
      response => { this.blocks = response },
      error => { // handle error }
    )
  };
}
```

Component A - Template

```html
<ng-container *ngIf="blocks">
  <div *ngFor="let block of blocks"></div>
</ng-container>

<app-component-b (refreshData)="getData()"></app-component-b>
```

Component B - Controller

```js
import { Component, EventEmitter, Output } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-component-b',
})
export class ComponentB {
  @Output() refreshData = new EventEmitter<boolean>();

  emitRefresh() {
    this.refreshData.emit(true);
  }
}
```

Component B - Template

```html
<button (mouseup)="emitRefresh()">Refresh Data</button>
```

Now the data in Component A will be refreshed each time the `Refresh Button` is pressed in Component B.

If you are worried about memory lead issues since we aren't using `async` anymore, it is handled by the HttpClient. So it is normal to subscribe to the HTTP call in the controller instead of the template.